# I need some with install or creating an app using terminal from Mac

Tags: macos, react-native

I am new to this world of PHP, javascript, app creating, and working in the terminal from my Mac. If you respond please dumb it down for me. Just what to be real with my level.

I have been trying to get the JCOW app up, here is where I am at; Create a new expo project (Example name: myapp)

expo init myapp
cd myapp

Once I do this it asks for me to choose a template but the problem is the next step from the instructions doesn't mention this. They say: Import Jcow React Native source code

Unzip your Jcow Ultimate Edition, you get a "mobile" folder. Copy files from that folder to "myapp". Use npm install to install dependencies from package.json.
Edit config.tsx, set the value of url to your own Jcow website URL.

I have selected the: Choose a template: › minimal               bare and minimal, just the essentials to get you started

When I move to the next instruction: Test your app

Run `expo start' to start development server and you will see a QR code on commend line terminal. Search and install "Expo" app from app store. Scan the QR code using Expo app and you will open your app. While testing your app, you should create at least 3 screenshots that will be used when submitting app.

Type in "start expo" here is what I get: Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
├─ getExpoSDKVersion /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Project.ts:23:9
├─ ensureConfigHasDefaultValues /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Config.ts:478:18
├─ fillAndReturnConfig /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Config.ts:103:10
├─ getConfig /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Config.ts:179:10
├─ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/utils/profileMethod.ts:16:21
├─ action /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:29:24
├─ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:124:22
└─ expo start /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:347:7

Any idea or help would be great. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have managed to make it this far: 14:52
Starting Metro Bundler
Error
16:58
ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/seanr.harrison/.expo/tmp-download-file.download' -> '/Users/seanr.harrison/.expo/tmp-download-file'
Error
16:58
ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/Users/seanr.harrison/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.18.4.tar.app'
Info
16:59
Info
16:59
This download is taking longer than expected. You can also try downloading the clients from the website at https://expo.io/tools